# JPQL NEW operator with native query ?

Tags: jpql

Can I use the `NEW` JPQL operator to map result of query inside `DTO` ?

I tested this code :

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT NEW com.sim.dtos.entities.FreeLocation(t1.galaxie, t1.ss, t1.position) FROM ...");

List<FreeLocation> l = query.getResultList();
```

But I have exception :

> [#|2012-12-20T12:9:21.203+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=79;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR: erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « . »
>     Position : 15

So can I use `NEW` operator with native query please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A native query, by definition, is a SQL query. It must contain valid SQL for your specific database.

The query will return a `List<Object[]>`, and it should be trivial to iterate through the list and create a new instance of `FreeLocation` for each `Object[]` array.

Comment: Ok thank you JB. So I can't use NEW constructor operator for native query ? In Eclipse, I have warning when I use `List<Object[]> list = query.getResultList();` -> `Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List<Object[]>`. Is this normal ? Using `List<?>` remove warning but I lose automatic casting

Comment: Yes, it's normal since the method returns a raw List. You know from the documentation that it contains Object[]. Just ignore the warning: it's unavoidable.

Comment: ok thank you. I'll will use @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") on my List so